# Accumulating plot of data and fit in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a Matlab script that imports data from a file and creates an exponential fit. I want the script to plot the data points and the fit using the same colour. The legend should be the name of the data file. When I run this same script again for another input file I want the new data and fit to be displayed in the same plot window name of the new data file added to the legend.

What I have so far is this;

```
expfit = fit(x,y,'exp1')

figure(1)
hold all
plot(x,y,'*','DisplayName','fileName)
legend('Interpreter','none')
legend show
```

using

```
plot(expfit,x,y,'DisplayName','fileName')
```

does not work

How can I add the fitted line to each data using the same colour as the data and
adding the filenames to the legend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...

An easy way is to get the colours up front

```
c = parula(7); % default colour map with 7 colours

figure(1); clf;
hold on
% filename is a variable e.g. filename = 'blah.csv'; from where the data was loaded
plot( x, y, '*', 'DisplayName', filename, 'color', c(1,:) );
plot( expfit, x, y, '-', 'HandleVisibility', 'off', 'color', c(1,:) );
legend('show');
```

Note by setting `HandleVisibility` off the fit will not show up in the legend. This is personal preference, I only like one entry for the data and the fit, you could instead use the `DisplayName` on the 2nd plot too.

Both plots use the same colour using the `color` input. I've used the first row of the colour map for both, if you plotted some other data you could use the 2nd row etc.

The alternative is to let MATLAB determine the colour automatically and just copy the colour over for the 2nd plot, you need to create a variable (`p`) of the first plot to get the colour

```
p = plot( x, y, '*', 'DisplayName', filename );
plot( expfit, x, y, '-', 'HandleVisibility', 'off', 'color', p.Color );
```

The other code would be the same.

Comment: I'm getting for plot (expfit,x,y,'-','HandleVisibility','off','color',p.Color)
 "Error in cfit/plot 
[S1,xdata,ydata,S2,outliers,S3,ptypes,conflev] = parseinput(alltypes,varargin)"
I'm using Matalb R2021a

Comment: You need to edit your question to include a full [mcve], I cannot reproduce your error without a full example. The fact you're loading from a file should be irrelevant as long as you can show some dummy data which reproduces your issue

Comment: here is an example 
x = 0:1:10;
y = 1:-0.1:0;
mdl = fit(x', y', 'exp1')
figure(1);
clf;
hold on
p = plot(x', y', '*', 'DisplayName', 'filename');
plot(mdl, x', y', '-', 'HandleVisibility', 'off', 'color', p.Color);
legend show;

This returns the following:
Error using cfit/plot>parseinput (line 354)
Argument 7 is incorrect

Error in cfit/plot (line 46)
[S1,xdata,ydata,S2,outliers,S3,ptypes,conflev] = parseinput(alltypes,varargin);

Comment: What works for me is to create a new response vector from the fitting parameters and plotting that data. Like this
mdl_out = mdl.a*exp(mdl.b*x)
plot(x,mdl_out,'-','HandleVisibility','off','color',p.Color)
plotting directly the fit object does not want to work this way